# CPU-core temperature rising quickly since switching to Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, cpu, fan, temperature

Ever since switching to Linux from windows my fans have been going faster overall, especially when using a lot of RAM. I changed fan-settings and now it seems like my CPU-core temperature rises insanely fast when switching to tasks that use more RAM.

I monitored my CPU-core temperature in an empty Chrome-tab which is about 45°C - 50°C whereas switching to a tab running a twitch livestream the temperatures rose to about 80°C in 5 seconds and to about 90°C in 20 seconds.

System specs  CPU: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11700KF @ 3.60GHz and GPU (I'm not sure if this is right, I used lspci) : VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2488 (rev a1)

Is this normal or is there something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Twitch uses ffmpeg for video display.

If ffmpeg is not installed, you should install it.
On Ubuntu the command is:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```